# Python Sklearn TfidfVectorizer Feature not matching; delete?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I trained a classifier using TfidfVectorizer in Sklearn. I then pickled the model for future use.

The new x_test that I want to make predictions on, has more features than the x_train from the model. This is the resulting error:

```
ValueError: X has 4877 features per sample; expecting 2799
```

Is there a way to delete any features in x_test that were not used in x_train?

I know if I had used a countverctorizer, i could have bypassed the error by not using fit_transform on x_test. But since it is TfidfVectorizer, it won't let me bypass.

I also tried imputation but couldn't get it to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not experience this problem if you use TfidfVectorizer properly.

Demo:

```
In [58]: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
```

source text

```
In [59]: text = """I trained a classifier using TfidfVectorizer in Sklearn. I then pickled the model for future use.
    ...:
    ...: The new x_test that I want to make predictions on, has more features than the x_train from the model. This is the resulting error"""
```

let's tokenize it to a list of sentenses:

```
In [60]: from nltk import  sent_tokenize

In [61]: vect = TfidfVectorizer()

In [62]: data = sent_tokenize(text)
```

yields:

```
In [63]: data
Out[63]:
['I trained a classifier using TfidfVectorizer in Sklearn.',
 'I then pickled the model for future use.',
 'The new x_test that I want to make predictions on, has more features than the x_train from the model.',
 'This is the resulting error']
```

now we can fit and transform our data set:

```
In [64]: X = vect.fit_transform(data)
```

result:

```
In [65]: X
Out[65]:
<4x31 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 34 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [66]: vect.get_feature_names()
Out[66]:
['classifier',
 'error',
 'features',
 'for',
 'from',
 'future',
 'has',
 'in',
 'is',
 'make',
 'model',
 'more',
 'new',
 'on',
 'pickled',
 'predictions',
 'resulting',
 'sklearn',
 'tfidfvectorizer',
 'than',
 'that',
 'the',
 'then',
 'this',
 'to',
 'trained',
 'use',
 'using',
 'want',
 'x_test',
 'x_train']
```

now let's feed it a data set with unknown words (features):

```
In [67]: new_dataset = ["let's see what happens to unknown words", "Yet another sentence."]

In [68]: X2 = vect.transform(new_dataset)

In [69]: X2
Out[69]:
<2x31 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

it worked properly - all unknown features (words) have been ignored:

```
In [70]: pd.SparseDataFrame(X2, columns=vect.get_feature_names(), default_fill_value=0)
Out[70]:
   classifier  error  features  for  from  future  has   in   is  make   ...     the  then  this   to  trained  use  using  want  \
0         0.0    0.0       0.0  0.0   0.0     0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   ...     0.0   0.0   0.0  1.0      0.0  0.0    0.0   0.0
1         0.0    0.0       0.0  0.0   0.0     0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   ...     0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0      0.0  0.0    0.0   0.0

   x_test  x_train
0     0.0      0.0
1     0.0      0.0

[2 rows x 31 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive reply. Ive been trying for hours to solve an issue i'm having using your code. Sent_tokenize is giving me an error: expected string or bytes-like object; i tried using nltk word_tokenizer. But couldn't figure it out. I'm very new at this. Can i share my full code with you to have a look? And how would i be able to share? I don't code area like they have on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Yousuf, please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) an answer if you think it has answered your question

Comment: @Yousuf, the best option would be to prepare a small reproducible data set and post it somewhere (GitHub, any file-exchange web site) and ask a new question (including your code). But the most important thing is a small reproducible data set and your desired data set...

Comment: Doing the same thing but I wanted to try something different. I don't want unknown features to be ignored. I want them to participate in prediction. Any idea from where I can start.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to delete exactly those features (columns) that are not known to your model.

Imagine that you trained your model on the following features:

- human weight
- human height
- sex
- age

and now you want to feed it a test data set containing the following features:

- human weight
- human height
- sex
- age
- eye color
- name
- zip code

so if if you randomly reduce it to the correct shape and get:

- eye color  (should be: human weight)
- human height
- zip code  (should be: sex)
- name (should be: age)

what kind of accuracy would you expect in this case?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is true. So do i have to manually delete those from my file? Or is there a function ?

Comment: @Yousuf, well it depends on how do you process your data... If you know indices of needed features, then it's fairly easy to implement in Numpy or Pandas ...